# How can I read specifc file by filename when using yauzl?

Tags: node.js, zip, fs, yauzl

I have to extract files from a zip archive and after that process it.

The thing is that each archive will have it own **manifest** file, and I have to check if its valid. How can I firstly check the **manifest** file and processed only if its available and is valid?